# SharePoint Online Communication Site- Quick Links-3 Layers

Tags: sharepoint-online, communication-site, quick-links

I am working on the Quick Links Webpart on the SharePoint Online Communications Page. I am trying to have Quick Links show 3 nested layers. But from whatever I have seen so far it is not possible. So, what would be the best way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two main options: first is to just add a text web part and manually add links, formatting as desired. Another option is to get out Visual Studio Code and create a custom SPFx part that implements your own custom version of the quicklinks part.

If you don't know javascript, the SPFx route is not a trivial undertaking, but if you want to look into that possibility, the SharePoint starter kit has a [web part](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-starter-kit/blob/master/documentation/components/wp-links.md) that has a links part with two levels.